# How can turbulence length scale be estimated from hydraulic diameter in pipe flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I want to model turbulent flow in fully developed pipe flow using an eddy diffusion coefficient *K* [m^2/s]. Using gradient diffusion theory, *K* can be obtained as

> *K* = *u* * *x*

where *u* [m/s] denotes a characteristic velocity scale, which I choose as the cross-sectional average flow velocity, and ***x* denotes the turbulence length scale**. *x* could be chosen as the size of the largest eddies in turbulent flow in my scenario.

In a [CFD Wiki](https://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Turbulence_length_scale), I found that *x* can be obtained as

> *x* = 3.8% * *d*

where *d* [m] denotes the pipe diameter. My question is, where do the 3.8% come from? My guess is this stems from measurement data. However, I can't find a source for it. Any reference to this number or a similar model would be appreciated!